# remove columns from Grid view if there is no data on it

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

how can I remove or disappear columns from Grid view if those columns dose not contain any values?

Comment: Have you tried setting Visible=false on the column?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a global boolean for the column you want to test such as:

```
bool columnHasValues = false;
```

Then in the `GridView.RowItemDataBound` event you would test that column for a value:

```
if (!columnHasValues)
    columnHasValues = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells(columnIndex).Text);
```

For .Net 4.0 change `IsNullorEmpty` to `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. Then in the `Page_PreRender` event, you would set that column's visibility to match the value of `columnHasValues`.